# self join to add previous month(s) values

Tags: r

This is my clumsy attempt to self join a time series data frame and add a column of the previous month:

```
df <- data.frame(
    date = c(
        as.Date("2015-1-1")
        , as.Date("2015-2-1")
        , as.Date("2015-3-1")
        , as.Date("2015-4-1")
        , as.Date("2015-5-1")
        , as.Date("2015-6-1")
        , as.Date("2015-7-1")
        , as.Date("2015-8-1")
        , as.Date("2015-9-1")
        , as.Date("2015-10-1")
        , as.Date("2015-11-1")
        , as.Date("2015-12-1")
    )
    ,value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
) %>%
    mutate(
        previous_month = date %m+% months(-1)
    )

temp <- df %>%
    left_join(df, by = c("previous_month" = "date")) %>%
    mutate(
        value.y = ifelse(is.na(value.y), 0, value.y)
    )
temp
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this (for n previous months) and also control the naming of the created value columns (e.g. value.y)? Thanks!

PS:

This is an option - see accepted answer.

```
df <- data.frame(
    date = c(
        as.Date("2015-1-1")
        , as.Date("2015-2-1")
        , as.Date("2015-3-1")
        , as.Date("2015-4-1")
        , as.Date("2015-5-1")
        , as.Date("2015-6-1")
        , as.Date("2015-7-1")
        , as.Date("2015-8-1")
        , as.Date("2015-9-1")
        , as.Date("2015-10-1")
        , as.Date("2015-11-1")
        , as.Date("2015-12-1")
    )
    ,value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
) %>%
mutate(
    month_minus_1 = lag(value, n=1)
    , month_minus_2 = lag(value, n=2)
    , month_minus_3 = lag(value, n=3)
    , month_minus_4 = lag(value, n=4)
    , month_minus_5 = lag(value, n=5)
    , month_minus_6 = lag(value, n=6)
)

df
```

Comment: Maybe `lag` ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `lag` function from `dplyr`. What would you like as the value for the first `previous_month` column? In here I kept it `NA`. You could also opt to create the `previous_month` column the way you did and only use `lag` for the `previous_value` column.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(previous_month = lag(date),
         previous_value = lag(value,default =  0))

1  2015-01-01     1           <NA>              0
2  2015-02-01     2     2015-01-01              1
3  2015-03-01     3     2015-02-01              2
4  2015-04-01     4     2015-03-01              3
5  2015-05-01     5     2015-04-01              4
6  2015-06-01     6     2015-05-01              5
7  2015-07-01     7     2015-06-01              6
8  2015-08-01     8     2015-07-01              7
9  2015-09-01     9     2015-08-01              8
10 2015-10-01    10     2015-09-01              9
11 2015-11-01    11     2015-10-01             10
12 2015-12-01    12     2015-11-01             11
```

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I do not want to have the previous month date. I just want to bold on the previous months values. Let us say month_minus_1, month_minus_2, month_minus_3. I will delete rows with missing values anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As noted `lag()` is the function you're looking for, but if you want to apply it multiple time or an undefinite number of times it can become problematic as we would have to create and name each column.

Using `mutate_at` we can apply multiple function to the same (or multiple columns).
So we need to build a list of functions that do the work we want:

```
lags_list <- 1:3 %>% 
  map(~partial(lag, n=.x, default=0)) %>% 
  set_names(paste0('lag', 1:3))
```

`lag_list` is now a list of function in the form `lag(x, n=1, default=0)` where `n` changes for each element of the list.

Now we can simply apply to our column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lags_list <- 1:3 %>% 
  map(~partial(lag, n=.x, default=0)) %>% 
  set_names(paste0('lag', 1:3))


df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(value), lags_list)
#>          date value lag1 lag2 lag3
#> 1  2015-01-01     1    0    0    0
#> 2  2015-02-01     2    1    0    0
#> 3  2015-03-01     3    2    1    0
#> 4  2015-04-01     4    3    2    1
#> 5  2015-05-01     5    4    3    2
#> 6  2015-06-01     6    5    4    3
#> 7  2015-07-01     7    6    5    4
#> 8  2015-08-01     8    7    6    5
#> 9  2015-09-01     9    8    7    6
#> 10 2015-10-01    10    9    8    7
#> 11 2015-11-01    11   10    9    8
#> 12 2015-12-01    12   11   10    9
```

We can also create a function to do it more elegantly:

```r
add_lags <- function(data, col, n) {
  lags_list <- 1:n %>% 
    map(~partial(lag, n=.x, default=0)) %>% 
    set_names(paste0('lag', 1:n))

  data %>% 
    mutate_at(vars({{col}}), lags_list)
}

df %>% add_lags(value, n=5)
#>          date value lag1 lag2 lag3 lag4 lag5
#> 1  2015-01-01     1    0    0    0    0    0
#> 2  2015-02-01     2    1    0    0    0    0
#> 3  2015-03-01     3    2    1    0    0    0
#> 4  2015-04-01     4    3    2    1    0    0
#> 5  2015-05-01     5    4    3    2    1    0
#> 6  2015-06-01     6    5    4    3    2    1
#> 7  2015-07-01     7    6    5    4    3    2
#> 8  2015-08-01     8    7    6    5    4    3
#> 9  2015-09-01     9    8    7    6    5    4
#> 10 2015-10-01    10    9    8    7    6    5
#> 11 2015-11-01    11   10    9    8    7    6
#> 12 2015-12-01    12   11   10    9    8    7
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

(Using you data:)

```r
df <- data.frame(
  date = c(
    as.Date("2015-1-1")
    , as.Date("2015-2-1")
    , as.Date("2015-3-1")
    , as.Date("2015-4-1")
    , as.Date("2015-5-1")
    , as.Date("2015-6-1")
    , as.Date("2015-7-1")
    , as.Date("2015-8-1")
    , as.Date("2015-9-1")
    , as.Date("2015-10-1")
    , as.Date("2015-11-1")
    , as.Date("2015-12-1")
  )
  ,value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.